# Embedded fonts in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I've tried a lot with embedding a font in a wpf app in c#. The font's name is 'Roboto'. The filename is *roboto.ttf* if that's of use.
I've made sure it's compiled in the assembly. So how to apply the font in a `TextBlock` for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply your font in an element like this:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="./#Roboto" ... />
```

Or you can specify the font's filename like this;

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="./roboto.ttf" ... />
```

You can also specify "./#Roboto Light" for example if you want the light font if it's embedded too.