# Convert byte[] to System.Windows.Media.FontFamily using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a byte array into application's resources. This is a custom font style.
I want convert this byte array to `System.Windows.Media.FontFamily`.

My code :

```
byte[] fontdata = Application_IAD.Properties.Resources.Sansation_Regular;

unsafe
{
     fixed (byte* pFontData = fontdata)
     {
         pfc.AddMemoryFont((System.IntPtr)pFontData, fontdata.Length);
     }
}
```

With this code, I have a `Sytem.Drawing.FontFamily` but I can't convert it to `System.Windows.Media.FontFamily`.

Can you help me ?

Comment: This is not correct code, the pointer you pass *must* stay valid as long as the font can be used.  It doesn't, the garbage collector mucks it up when it compacts the heap.  Google "addmemoryfont marshal.alloccotaskmem", avoid the *many* buggy examples that call Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem() right away.

Comment: Why don't you just package the `Font` with application ? Read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms753303(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: With the website that you give me, i can't make that Jasper can you help me ?

Comment: In what format is the data? Presumably, it's some kind of .ttf, .otf, etc. right? You can't use `System.Drawing` to create objects that are used by WPF (i.e. `System.Windows.Media`). But WPF allows you to read fonts directly. See e.g. [Embedded fonts in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22885883) or [How to use font in the references library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30120635). The link Jasper offered also has useful information. If none of that helps, provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Had similar needs, here is my approach (Assuming you don't know the font family name and font is not embedded). 
If someone has a better idea, don't hesitate to add some comments, please!

```
        //Writing bytes to a temporary file.
        string tempFontFileLoation = "testFont.ttf";
        File.WriteAllBytes(tempFontFileLoation, yourBytesHere);

        //Creating an instance of System.Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface.
        //From here we will read all the needed font details.
        var glyphTypeface = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri(tempFontFileLoation));

        //Reading font family name
        string fontFamilyName = String.Join(" ", glyphTypeface.FamilyNames.Values.ToArray<string>());

        //This is what we actually need... the right font family name, to be able to create a correct FontFamily Uri
        string fontUri = new Uri(tempFontFileLoation.Replace(Path.GetFileName(tempFontFileLoation), ""), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute).AbsoluteUri + "/#" + fontFamilyName;

        //And here is the instance of System.Windows.Media.FontFamily
        var fontFamily = new FontFamily(fontUri);
```

Comment: I have found a solution to my problem. I expose you my idea. You put your font into the project resources. So a byte array is create. After, you can create a `FontFamily` like this : `FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/"), "./#Your font Name");` I'll hope this help you ;-)